# Blender only renders black frames

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I've been working on a project that contains a building with some textures and materials and an animation. When finished I wanted to render the scene. I rendered the animation using jpeg as output. But when I went to the output folder all the frames created turned out to be pitch black.

Even as I try to render a single image I get this window[image]

using cycles render I get this result

[image]

Also the rendering time is extremely short and as my scene is quite complicated I think that it doesn't consider my scene at all.

Can someone help me render my scene?

Comment: I think a .blend file, which you can [upload here](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) would help us understand your issue. Add it to your post as an edit. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Figured it out. The composition checkbox and the sequencer check box should not be checked. You can find these checkboxes in the properties panel under render under post processing. [image]

[image]

Make sure these aren't checked and it should work.

Comment: This isn't the best workflow. It's good to unckeck them just in testing purposes but once it's clear one of them causing that it's better to investigate sequencer's clips and compositor's nodes. Sequencer and compositor are too good features to not use them at all.

Comment: Thanks this was it!

Answer (score 3):

Possible causes for a blank render:

- There are no lights in scene
- [Objects disabled for Render in Outliner (camera icon)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27721/one-object-wont-show-up-in-final-render-even-though-it-shows-up-in-the-preview/27722#27722)
- [If Strips are present in VSE and Sequencer box enabled in Post-Processing those will take precedenceo over 3d scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51179/blank-image-when-i-render/51181#51181)
- [Objects in different layer or not part of the render Layers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35020/1853)
- Camera view blocked by other objects
- Active camera aiming in a different direction
- An object in the scene set as camera
- Output node in compositor disconnected
- [Film exposure is set to 0 (Cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51951/my-render-is-turning-out-black/51957#51957)