# Blank image when I render

Tags: rendering

I went to animate a project, Blender was returning a blank screen.
I have attempted to restart both Blender and my laptop, as well as re-downloading the program.

With each attempt, Blender exported a black movie, which I attempted to watch multiple times.
I even attempted to reanimate one of my older Blender files, and even that reexported as a black movie.

[image: Blender screen after pressing animation]

Old File
[image]

Newer File
[image]

Comment: @cegaton Aha! You've made me an inch smarter, thanks. Strange i didn't notice when comparing it to a working .blend. Also i'm going to bed now so you can fill in a answer if you wish, if not i can do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are unused strips on the VSE. If the Sequencer box is checked that takes priority over the 3D scene render...
Uncheck Sequencer and you will be able to render the scene.

[image]

(for versions previous to 2.8:)

[image]