# Rendering produces a completely transparent image with no objects

Tags: rendering

I have a scene with animated objects. In 3d view and camera view i can see them perfectly with material and textures

but every time i render (F12) i get this result[image]

just a transperent screen
i tried to put the objects into another scene/project but they didn't appear
also it once said there aren't any objects in there...

Comment: Disable use compositing in Properties Window > Render Tab > Post Processing Panel > Compositing.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51179/blank-image-when-i-render

Comment: see if any of the listed causes of blank images applies in your case: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Answer (score 0):

Start with pycoder's comment (I can't comment because I'm new to Stack Exchange).

Also check the camera's clipping settings. Select the camera, Properties Window > Camera Tab > Lens > Clipping. The values are blender's units and the default is 100 (way too short in many cases).

Comment: Looking at the screenshot I actually doubt that clipping is the problem here. Even if clipping is screwed up and all objects are cut off the renderer should still render the world's default background. It might be that I'm wrong of course.