# Intro hindering animation

Tags: rendering, animation

[image]I downloaded an intro for a project and now have the project based around it. However, whenever I render the animation all it plays is the intro and the rest is a screen saying," Goalartz and Roodified" This is the link: https://www.mediafire.com/?pk24ubp71hi8pug please post suggestions in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking, please edit your question and provide more details on what you want to achieve. Check the compositing nodes if the render output is different from the viewport preview.

Comment: See if [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/51179/2217) solves your issue.