# My render is turning out black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9MnoB3KD97sbjNJQWg1MWkyNnc&usp=sharing

I have a light source, but it renders black

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to the Blender StackExchange community! This is a question and answer site, not a forum, so it might be helpful to take our tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour to get a feel for what we're about. In short, please add more information to your question about the problem you're experiencing and what you've tried to fix it. Screenshots are super helpful for people who want to answer, but don't have Blender in front of them to look at your file. BlenderArtists is a great place to get technical help, if your problem is too specific for BSE.

Comment: Please  don't make your questions dependent on a file only, add a description of your issues and images on your post. If the link to your file disappears, other users facing the same issue will not be able to learn from your question.

Comment: Quick, everybody, down vote him! He's new and we should make sure he can never comment on other people's things ever again! Get him!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error on your file is that you set film exposure to 0, making everything... black. It's like taking a photograph with the lights off (or with the lens cap on).

[image]

Set it back to one!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something must be wrong with your scene properties. I appended (`Shift F1`) all the objects into a new file and it rendered just fine, although it didn't copy your compositing setup.

Comment: Though this might solve the problem, it only masks the origin, and it's hard to learn then what went wrong. My feeling is that unless the file is corrupt due to some bug, appending everything to a new file should be the very last resource.