# The object is turning black while rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm a Blender beginner and I have the following problem: My glass material turns black when I render the image, as you can see below:

[image]

I have already tried using the "Transparent" option as suggested in this answer: [My render is turning out black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51951/my-render-is-turning-out-black)

But it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: In the settings of your glass material (Material Properties), setting the 'ShadowMode' to 'Alpha Hashed' should solve the issue. (the objects inside the globe aren't able to recieve light, since the globe is Shadow opaque). ;)

Comment: It helped, thank you so much!!!