# cycles isnt working when rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

I'm used to rendering heavier files but cycles isn't rendering the one I'm currently working on for some reason, it renders just fine in the viewport even with the sampling increased exponentially and it still only takes around 60mb of memory but when I render the scene it says out of memory and doesn't render. plus the model isn't visible through the camera with viewport render.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4926" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4926/)

Comment: there is an [edit] link at the bottom of your post so that you can include the link as part of the question an not as a comment.

Comment: Issue is with memory . I think you are using the GPU for cycles rendering ..try switching to ram.

Comment: Read: [Blender render crash when using subsurf modifiers.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283)

Comment: I'm using CPU rendering as blender doesn't support my GPU

Comment: I did get the model out in one piece though, by exporting it as an obj file and then opening it in a fresh blender file.

Comment: Checked the model..It crashed my system too :D..you have to reduce the subdivision levels

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Rendered image is just grey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/rendered-image-is-just-grey/55411#55411)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

The first one is that you have set the subsurf modifier to a very high number of subdivisions for rendering.

[image]

You have to be careful when using the subsurf modifier, as it increases the number of vertices exponentially. Using a large number of vertices will require more RAM and will use more computing resources.
I doubt you need 6 levels of subdivision ever. With 6 levels of subdivision your very simple scene needs 6.5GB of RAM to render.

Use a more reasonable number. Read: [Blender render crash when using subsurf modifiers.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers/28283#28283)

The second problem is that you are trying to use depth of field on the camera, but have set the focus distance to zero, so your scene is completely out of focus, and it renders all gray.
[image]

Set the focus  to the distance of the object , or select the object as your focus target.

[image]

Read:

[Rendered image is just grey](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55410/rendered-image-is-just-grey/55411#55411)