# Blender intro turns black after rendering

Tags: rendering, video

So I recently rendered an intro overnight and when I woke up the blender intro was a black screen. I scrolled through all the frames and they were still black but the audio would still play.

Comment: Could you please pack external data and upload a .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ?

Comment: For possible causes for blank render see this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Comment: First thing I always do is try turning on Environment Lighting in the Properties editor > World context.