# Black Screen After Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

My intro finished rendering then it went black (the screen). I it by pressing 'Play' but I only saw a black screen with the music playing. Can anyone help me get it back to the normal intro please.

[image]

Comment: see if any of this helps: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Comment: Select Render > Play Back Rendered Animation in the top menu and see if your animation plays.

Answer (score 2):

Your image viewer is set to the composite. If you use nodes in your composite, it's possible you forgot to connect your last node to the output. The composite will just show up black, like you showed. If you didn't want to use the compositor, just uncheck "use nodes" in the node editor.

To access the node editor, just click the farthest left button in the 3d view, then select node editor, and make sure it is set to the composite nodes.

[image: Node Editor]

Alternatively, you can just uncheck "compositing", under post processing in the properties pane:

[image]

Comment: Where Is The Node Editor?

Answer (score 0):

Select *View Layer* in the header of the image editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.1 I had to set the view layer to "Noisy Image" because apparently "Combined" was just black, even though I disabled compositing outright.

[image]