# Particle Emission Rendering as Black Screen

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I've been trying to learn Blender and I had a whole scene created and it was working fine. I rendered out a very nice background at 7980 x 2160, but then I tried to make a video of the same scene at 1920 x 1080 and the screen is totally black. I've read through all the other posts on here that are similar and some of the posts on other forums and I cannot seem to figure this one out.

I've tried all the things mentioned in the other posts, but none of the posted fixes seems to fix my problem. Such as disabling the sequencer, or changing the film transparency setting. Here is my blender file:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23049559/Sparks_005.blend

Some of the other posts that I tried to follow to solution this problem:

1. [Black Screen Cycles Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48051/black-screen-cycles-render)
2. [cycles not rendering movie clip used as background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-movie-clip-used-as-background/38464#38464)
3. [Black Screen After Rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60636/black-screen-after-rendering)

This is the tutorial I was working off of: https://youtu.be/QCMyvcc3ZaU

Any ideas?
I am using the cycles render.

Comment: There is something wrong with your download link, please update it, it is transfering as a text file. You scene is completely dark and devoid of lamps, lighting or light sources of any kind. There is probably something wrong with your material definition, the age/lifetime node combination is yielding a black material

Comment: Right click on the link and click save link as. It will let you save the file to your local system as a blend file. I just checked the material definitions, they are good, the material is a light emitter, unless I changed something by accident. I don't remember changing anything that would cause it to turn black. I've tried everything I can think of...I'm at a loss, and I'm still new & just learning.

Comment: Yeah, I already did, but next time use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for sharing files here. Anyway your file is all black when I opened here, particles were not emitting any light, except for the original icosphere bellow the ground plane

Comment: Ahhh copy that on the file sharing. Thanks I will do that in the future. Ok so then you have reproduced my issue. No idea what is wrong? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Yeah, your material definition is wrong. Something about your math with particle age and life is off in your node setup, making particles emission dark. Check your node setup and check the tutorial, something must be amiss there.

Comment: Could it be that the computation of the particle path has caused the system to mess up the age calculation causing all of the particles to show an incorrect age? I've been fiddling with this blender file for days now and clicked recompute on the particles several times just playing around with the system trying to figure out how it works. Is this even a remote possibility? I changed the icosphere material to Material.005 and glow is back but the age effect is not....of course because Material.006 is the one with the age. So I believe you are right.

Comment: I just cannot figure out what is wrong with the age calculation for Material.006. I will try and re-model the nodes for Material.006 as Material.007 and see what I can discover.

Comment: Ok yea I played around with this a bit and finally got it working. I remodeled the texture, and it was also working just fine until I tied up the value of the Divide node to the Mix Shader node in the Fac shader input. Once I tied that up the texture came up as black, but without the divide tied to the fac input of the mix shader the texture works perfect. Any idea why? Is this a new bug? Or is it something wrong with my setup?

Comment: Ok I think I got it now!! I've got a bunch more details into what is going on here after trying out a bunch of stuff and playing with it for about an hour or so. Do you want me to post an answer to this question with all the details I've learned or do you want to convert it to an answer?

Comment: You should post it as an answer for future reference or possible future visitors. Be sure to explain what the problem actually was and how to solve it.