# Render is all black

Tags: rendering

Hello I am relatively new to blender and have exhausted every outlet for advice that I can on this subject to no avail. So I am reaching out to you. I have imported a vector file of a logo with some text from Inkscape into blender and have converted it into a mesh and animated it. The scene is lit, the camera is properly placed, however when I go to render it the screen is all black (in blender render) and in cycles render it is all gray. I have tried a lot of things to fix this but none have worked. Do you have any suggestions?

*EDIT* [image]
This is the link to my .blend file
[image: Render settings]

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information. Please [edit] your question and show images of your render settings, materials and lighting. Look at the possible causes of blank rendering and see if any apply in your case: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Comment: And by the way blender and cycles materials are not interchangeable.

Comment: Do you know how to link a blender file into the question box?

Comment: To upload a file use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, but please add more information to the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. However I am so new that I'm not sure what else to add to the post. I don't know what information would be helpful. I will try though. I also don't know how to include cropped screen shots.

Comment: @cegaton it wont let me upload more than 2 links on here. If you think a different picture of my settings would be more beneficial let me know and I will switch them. Sorry again if my question is vague I don't know what else to do. I am open to all criticisms and suggestions.

Comment: @AntonioMattei Post the blendexhange link in the comments and one of us will put it in your answer

Comment: @10Replies by blendexchange link do you mean the link to my blend file?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2323" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2323/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all objects with <kbd>A</kbd>
Go in the Object Tab, in duplication panel and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Click on "none"
[image: click]

You also need to change your point light color (black light won't give anything).
result with white light
[image: render]

Answer (score 1):

First your sun is black, so make it white and you will have lighting (you will see your plane. Not sure about the logo though.

Answer (score 0):

To take a cropped screenshot, at least on a pc, search snipping tool in the search box on the start menu, then it should allow you to draw a box around what you want to capture and then copy that to your clipboard.

Comment: I'm on a mac, and this method was not successful. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: @AntonioMattei Type command shift 4... the screen shot will be on your desktop

Comment: @Cowcatcherer You have to have 50 reputation to comment

Comment: @10Replies I know, I just think it's silly that i can answer a question before I can comment. I would have loved to comment my help but allas I have not the reputation for such a thing yet. If it's an issue i can stop though.