# Render Obj is all black

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have an issue similar to [this problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68365/render-is-all-black)  when I want to render an 3D .obj, I tried the methods proposed and get the same result as following[image]

Firstly, I deleted the origin cube and import my .obj mesh car, then I shift the view to the local and use "Ctrl+Alt+ Numpad0" to align the camera to my viewport. Finally I click the "Render" button and come to this situation.

And my .blend file is also [attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fqRKJ_UsTYFKItEnc0ADhNldiMk2LBJB/view?usp=sharing).

Waiting for your help~

Comment: Try to adjust the lamp.

Comment: Thanks, following your advice, I change the lamp type from point to the Hemi, and enhance the light Eneregy to 2.0, and finally get a perfect result.