# Blank render in cycles

Tags: rendering, image

Hello can anyone tell me why this is happening.... here is my scene in the viewport shader with render ticked in object mode.[image]

However, when I render the image in cycles blender I get this.....

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Help.
Now it looks like this....
[image]

Comment: Where is your camera and where is it pointing?

Comment: See if any of the solutions on this post apply in your case: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Comment: Hello guys and thank you. I unchecked "Sequencer" in the post processing  render section. Now the scene objects are all black....

Comment: Camera is pointing towards a background that should have a lamp.

Comment: GOT IT... LOOKS LIKE MY LAYERS WERE OFF.....