# The render result is just the transparent texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I rendered a 1200x800 image, but it's just the transparent texture thing:

[image]

I used Cycles for this image. In a test in Blender Render, it worked perfectly, although the materials were made in Cycles so you obviously couldn't see them as you were supposed to.

Comment: Please look through the answers on these posts and see if any of the causes of blank rendering applies in your case: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up or on this link. or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a cycles material for visible your render because cycles engine needs nodes tree for render  you can't render blender internal  material into cycles render

Comment: I have cycle made materials w/ nodes

Comment: yes you need to change