# Render out an animation from Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes

I usually use After Effects for my compositing but thought I would try and give Blender a chance (since I really like the glare effect).

I have no clue why my renders keep coming out blank. What am I doing wrong?

I rendered out a 300 frame animation as an EXR. I then created a new scene and loaded in those 300 images as an image sequence. My node setup is below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the outputted image sequence:

[image]

Does it have something to do with this node?

[image]

Comment: @MrZak Nope I get a completely black (blank) image. I think I am using the compositor completely wrong. Not sure what I am missing. I updated with some new images.

Comment: Not sure how do you get node without any outputs.. But anyway if you add Image node, point it to rendered .exr (or just drag and drop exr on the compositor window) and connect *that* to the Composite node you should be fine. If your screenshots mean that you disabled RenderLayer and left it as connected to Composite node then it's obviously nothing will be rendered.

Comment: @MrZak Ok now I am really confused. To answer your response, isnt that what I did with the above pic? also I finally got it to render with the image. It looks like I had just one frame in the sequencer and because I wasnt on that one frame it was rendering blank. I just deleted that frame and it renders fine. But now I am having another issue with it re rendering my 3d model instead of using the image sequence I have already rendered. Im so lost. I will go read the manual a little more in depth. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Blender will render what is on render layer if RenderLayer node is present in the tree.. regardless whether it was connected or not. I'd suggest using one file for modeling and rendering and another for compositing and not mix them up, this could allow to avoid confusing.

Comment: @MrZak  Thank you. I opened up a brand new file and everything is working perfect. I think I will stick to your way for now until I better understand the nodes in compositor. One last (dumb) question. With the new blend file for compositing does render samples matter? I am just adding a glare effect and my original .exr's were rendered at 2000 samples. With the new compositing file what would the render samples be "sampling" how many samples do I need for just a glare effect? Thanks again.

Comment: Afaik it doesn't matter; compositor overpasses scene setup so as I tested it doesn't depend on sampling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Comment: I would close this, as the blank frames resulted from a frame in the sequencer. (The third solution in the linked answer.)