# Blender Renders Gray Full Screen

Tags: rendering, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

so I have been following these tutorials trying to create a robot dog. I followed them to a tea and then when I go to render the animation of the dog I was told to create in this tutorial I get a fully gray screen; frame after frame.  I look for the sampling section and I cannot find it. I don't know how to fix this so that it comes up with the actually rendered animation, as well as that I had some nodes for the dogs color and other aspects and they seem to have gone as well. Can anyone help?

Link to site: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4TkA5P5Qes

Dropbox Link to .blend file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqrrs2wcx9hsyg9/crappyDog.blend?dl=0

Comment: See if any of the cause for blank render applies in your case: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Comment: Sadly none of these fixed my problem...

Comment: Is your project created in cycles or blender internal? Did you accidentally change render engine? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccrHz.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Your project has materials for the cycles render engine. If you render on blender internal the file will not render correctly.

[image]

Materials form different render engines are not interchangeable.

[image]

Comment: Shiloh, @cegaton is correct when he writes that materials can only be used with the Render engine for which they were designed. However, beginning with Blender 2.78, while the materials are not interchangeable, they are convertible. As shown in this illustration, <https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l1Nu.jpg>, in the materials context panel of the properties editor are two panes, one converts materials from cycles to Blender internal, the other from Blender internal to Cycles. I don't know if these are available in 2.77 or not, as I don't have an active installation to check.