# Render is Completely Black

Tags: rendering

The problem that I am having, is that when I try and render my scene, everything turns out completely black. I press render, then it takes about 1 minute 30 seconds before it actually starts rendering, then it quickly renders a black screen. I have looked through many other posts about this, but none of the solutions are working for me. I'm a beginner, so I'm sure I am just missing something obvious, but help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Here is what renders.]

Comment: Are you sure there is a light or light source in your scene?

Comment: Please read through the following links and see if any of the proposed answers to applies in your case: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank and also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up