# Black Final Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

As in the title above, when I make "Shift Z" to go to the Render Mode, every thing look great, but when I make the final render it's just blank and nothing appears.

Note: I've tried most of the answer for the similar questions but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: try the solutions in these pages: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank If those solutions don't work please specify what you have tried already.

Comment: I've already tried all of them but I'm still facing the same issue, and I'm very sure it's something silly I've change when I was trying things, if there's a way I can upload the file that wold be great.

Comment: use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the resulting link as part of your original question.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3776" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3776/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render layers (in the scene tab of your properties panel) are not properly set up. Create a new render layer then disable the other two or delete them. 
The render should proceed normally after that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but it could be a compositing issue. Open a node editor, select the Scene tab on the bottom (looks like two stacked pictures), and make sure that either `Use Nodes` is off, or the Render Layers node is connected to the Composite node.