# When I render it I got a fully black image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am trying to make a 360degree photo. I just do such i saw in some you tube tutorials. I change blender render to cyclic render and change camera to panoramic .But when I render it I got a fully black image. How i can solve this.(hopping you can understand. Because my English is very bad)

This is my blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4E2Wd62ZA0Yc1J3ZFBFLThaRWM/view?usp=drivesdk

Can you just render it to image and show me it

Because I think it may be problem of my system.

[image: this is my project]
My project
[image: camera view]
Camera view
[image: rendering window]
Rendering window

Comment: Hello and welcome. We can understand just fine, but we can't help nontheless because we know nothing about your scene. Please edit your question and provide all relevant details.

Comment: Sir I edited it is it ok.please help

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend uploads and add the code it gives you into the question.

Comment: Try to flip normals of the mesh

Answer (score 2):

Black or blank output has been covered before. Look [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank).

You need to add a lamp to your scene. There is no source of light, and therefore the render is black. To add a lamp hit Shift+A while your mouse is in the 3d window, and select any lamp type as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Add lamp]

While the default position it is placed in might not be ideal, you could move the lamp after adding it. The render right after inserting the lamp will look like this:

[image: Rendering result]

Answer (score 1):

The image renders black, because you don't have any lights in your scene. I added a area lamp, that covers the cylinder and everything renders fine.

[image]

In your screenshot, there is a sun lamp in your scene (it wasn't in the .blend, you uploaded), but it can't illuminate the scene, because the sun lamp is a **global** light. So even if you position the sun lamp inside the cylinder, it will cast its light from infinitely far away and the cylinder wouldn't let any light through. Use **local** lamps, such as area-, point- and spot-lamps and position them inside the cylinder to light this scene. If you want to use the sun lamp, you could go to the object tab of your cylinder properties (the object tab is the orange cube) and uncheck "Shadow" in Cycles Settings, ray visibility. The light of the sun will pass through your cylinder and now illuminates the inside.