# Why are my preview renders good and my actual renders totally black

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm using Blender 2.79 and Cycles renderer.

Can't figure out why my pre view renders look like this

[image]

and my "rendered" images look like this.

[image]

Only a total noob to blender.  Have been using Modo, Max and Lightwave for about 15 years.

I've seen Render Layers as a common problem.  i don't think that is my issue

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Add screenshot of outliner, or post blend-file

Comment: Bit of a noob myself but do you have a camera in the scene and more importantly is it checked to render?

Comment: Thuis questinon gets asked frequently read through the following link and see if any of tha answets work for you https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  None of those things seem to the be the issue.  If anyone has the time to check out the blend file that would be awesome.         https://wetransfer.com/downloads/db3c95b4b577be2f51d4013ee47d523a20180202053201/79c70146860f04f987218daf3d9cd57c20180202053201/6fa110

Answer (score 2):

Sorry... I'm an idiot.  In case there is anybody else out there who might benefit from this.  I decided not to render the window panes and so i didn't make them transparent and I clicked the little eye icon to hide it in the 3D view.  So when you do a preview render in cycles it gives you a preview of what is visible in the 3D view.  However hiding something in 3D view doesn't mean that it won't render.  So my non transparent windows that were hidden in the 3D view were blocking the sunlight from coming into the room.  Lesson of the story is hit the little camera icon next to an object in the Outliner to make it invisible to the rendering engine.

Thanks again for the responses.