# Image renders as gray frame

Tags: rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, keyframes, frame-rate

I'm pretty new to Blender but I have basic knowledge after watching Blender Guru and other tutorials. I was working on a game character and once I finished and animated it I figured I'd render it to a file. Unfortunately no matter what I do it just renders completely gray frames. What I've tried:

Turn off sequencer.

Turn off compositor.

Change file format (Png, MPEG, etc.)

Delete any strips in Video Editor

Check layers and visibility

Any help at all is appreciated. Thanks so much in advance. Below is screen shot. If you need more info let me know.

[image: Screenshot When rendering]

Comment: The information you posted is not enough to know what is going on on your scene. Please read through the answers on this pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) and  [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up). See if any of the proposed causes/solutions apply in your case

Comment: I’ve looked through these a couple times but didn’t find a fix. I’ll look again when I get a chance. Appreciate the response. What other info would you need?

Comment: Yeah I would do that except the mesh I’ve modeled is for game development and I don’t exactly want it out in the open if you know what I mean. Any other information at all I can provide

Comment: I’ll post if I find a fix. Any other advice would be great if you can think because it is rendering just rendering grey

Comment: Read carefully through the posted links. This is a question that gets asked quite often. Also, if you are starting with blender try rendering at a smaller resolution first (8k is a bit too much) and less samples until you figure out your issues.

Comment: Alright sure. Thnx for the advice. I’ve rendered in 8k before but I agree with you about the res it’s just I animated in 8k so don’t want to mess up ratios. About the sampling don’t most use 1000-10000samples? For some reason I can barely do 1000 within the hour :).

Comment: you have other issues to resolve before the final high quality render IMHO...

Comment: What is IMHO? Yes I would agree