# Cycles render is blank and camera object changes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, camera

I have this problem where my scene render is blank, and I think I've figured out why, but it's weird. 
I set my scene camera to the actual camera object:

[image: camera set correctly]

But when I press f12 the render is blank. Not black, but transparent. Then for some reason, the camera object switches to 'bulb' by itself

[image]

Please help me out, this makes no sense.

 You can download the blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Buut_BoOPlHSyy0ZSKTolQhDD-_4lF0G/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: This could be very relevant to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108064/changing-active-camera-will-yield-an-incorrect-rendering-camera-view-not-reflec) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102129/render-results-always-black-the-first-time?noredirect=1&lq=1) based on my experience in the past.

Comment: @Amir Thanks for your comment, but I'm not using any scripts and I only have on camera in the scene, so I'm pretty sure my problem is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the `Bulb` object is bound to the marker `Jump`. See [this answer for details](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3503/599).

To fix it, you can either remove the marker (press <kbd>X</kbd> while hovering over it), or select your camera object and press *Timeline header > View > Bind camera to markers* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> in the timeline area).

Comment: @LeviJones Yep, definitely one of the more well hidden features :P