# Renders not showing at all

Tags: rendering

[image]So I'm working on . stupid noob question of the day here but I'm absolutely stumped. I was doing a tutorial on mist and volumetric lighting and only 1/2 following along and all of a suddenly I can only render in viewport. When I set up a render rather than a viewport preview render I get nothing but a black screen. The programme no longer goes round and collects and syncs the files, theres no little square boxes developing a picture.....nada! What button(s) did I hit that turned off the render function? What did I do? I've rebooted the whole system, I've gone back to previously saved files that rendered fine before .......seriously nothing......well a 5 second pause and then a black frame.

[image]

Comment: If you are so kind to show images that illustrate the issue it might be easier to help you. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Consider sharing your .blend file so that others can inspect it. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.

Comment: Please read through the answers on this pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) and  [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up). See if any of the proposed causes/solutions apply in your case