# Getting a grey image when rendering

Tags: rendering

When rendering, I only get a grey image.

[image: Scene]
[image: Render]

[Download files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/696o9pvq5xjd0e7/AACgHbt0tp8KM5SU29FI5M_Ta?dl=0)

Comment: Please read through the answers on this pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) and  [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up). See if any of the proposed causes/solutions apply in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clip distance on your camera is set to a very small range.

Enable display limits so that you can visualize the clipping range.

Then increase the range so that the camera can see your objects

[image]