# Cycles Renderer Not Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have made a very simple, basic ball animation with Blender, and was just going to render it (in Cycles). I want to render each frame as an image, so I set it to PNG. But when I render it, after about 5 seconds, it renders a bunch of black images. The render result does not even appear in the UV image Editor. Here is what it looks like when I hit the Render Animation button-
[image]

I am trying to render it with 128 samples, 32 preview. Here are my Render settings-
[image]
Here is the project file:
[image]
I am using Blender 2.79. Can anyone help me and tell me why my animation is not rendering?

Comment: Your screenshots are not enough to diagnose the issue. Please attach your blend file using the following link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The information you posted is not enough to know what is going on on your scene. Please read through the answers on this pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) and  [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up). See if any of the proposed causes/solutions apply in your case. If none of that helps, please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: You have a strip in your sequencer, Delete it or uncheck "sequencer" under render tab > post processing