# Camera can't see object, it only renders the background

Tags: rendering, particles, camera, smoke-simulation

I've got a problem while trying to create a smoke simulation in blender 2.79 (internal render). I have already made a simulation which is appearing in the render mode, but when I'm trying to render it with the camera, the smoke is not visible. I'm very new to blender.

- Rendered mode: [image: Rendered Mode]
- Camera Render Result: [image: Camera Render Result]
- .blend:
  https://drive.google.com/open?id=17eeY1EcQnSQOAV3Uwez6f3_Yr7RTAEIf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Oh ok. I'm sorry, I thought that it was the same as in stackoverflow that I was not able to post images directly

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clip distance for the camera is set at a very short range.

Your object is beyond the end clip distance and will not be seen by the camera unless you increase it.

[image]

Comment: That's it, thank you! Shall I rename this question?