# My render keeps coming out blank

Tags: rendering, animation

Every time I go to render this, it comes out totally blank. I'd also like to note that it's rendering REALLY fast. Not sure if that has anything to do with it
[[image: t]the render just keeps coming out like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxJ6A.png).

[image]

I tried the stuff from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) post but it didn't work.

Comment: Duarte - I tried a lot of the things that guy said and nothing worked. :(

Comment: You didn't, the solution is literally the third header of the linked answer. This question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck the sequenzer checkbox:

[image]

Comment: OMAGOSH. i have been trying to figure that out for a week now and u just fixed it in like 3 seconds lol.

Comment: You're welcome :)
(I had no Idea, honestly I was just lucky xD)