# Everything is gray

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, image

I have a bunch of scenes and there all correct but there's 1 that is broken. When I render its just all grey. There's nothing but grey.
My preview samples: 10
My render samples: 35
My GPU isn't that great, its a 920M GeForce Nvidia
Here's an image of the grey screen when I render it (In the viewport its all fine, everything shows up):

[[image: When rendering[![][1]]

Comment: It's certainly taking a while to render that gray! It looks black to me, actually. Do you have any lights? And does it have the same problem in Rendered view mode?

Comment: did you check for hidden geometry in the viewport that is rendering?

Comment: The information you posted is not enough to understand your scene and settings. Please **read carefully** through the answers on these pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632) and [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490). Try the proposed solutions. If you still can't solve your problem, then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add more information, and add images that illustrate on how you set up your project and settings.