# Strange render, though in object mode I can see the object just fine

Tags: camera

I am having a strange issue where I could see well through camera in object mode, but when I am trying to render it, the result seems to be grainy color of the object but the actual object is not visible. The following is the view through camera:

[image: view through camera]

after rendering the exact same frame.
[image: render of the exact same frame]

[image]

Added the blender file. Yes, I have tried the camera settings and added additional lights into the scene, it is rendering on the final frames, but it is not rendering in the very first frame, the camera is set to follow a simple path.

Comment: see if that is the correct frame render or you can have two or more cameras

Comment: One camera aligned to the object, and it is the correct frame.

Comment: This could have a number of reasons, e.g. invisible but renderable objects.As always: In this case, consider [uploading your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so that someone can have a closer look at it.

Comment: Press Alt+H i think its hidden and in camera its seen.

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/53633#53633

Comment: I have added a blend file in the question and added additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scene is enclosed inside a giant cube that is disabled for the viewport ( and enabled for render (camera icon).

[image]

What you see is the inside of that cube that has a very dense value for volume scatter. To view the animal like object in your scene you can disable the renderability(camera icon) of the cube  on the outliner or bring down the volume scatter to a more reasonable level.

[image]

Comment: What is the best way to debug this kind of error? Do you manually change the renderability of each of the elements, and do a check? Thank you this solved my problem.

Comment: You are compounding several variables without understanding what each one of them does. The problem with that approach is that it is not easy to see the effect of each one. Try one thing, see and understand what that particular tool does, and only then move to use other tools. Otherwise your learning experience can be a bumpy road.

Comment: Thanks :) Another question: the renders also seem very grainy, is it a result of poor lighting or do I need to increase the samples and resolution?

Comment: Please do not ask new questions as part of the comments. Use the [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) question link at the top of the page