# All renders are a black screen

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

We purchased a rigged human anatomy model. It has several layers, materials and textures and appears to be very complex. The scene came set up. I can see everything in rendered shading however when I actually go to render it out, the output is completely black. I'm using cycles, composite node is connected correctly, I have a camera and 2 lights. I've searched all over the web and have tried everything that is suggested and nothing seems to solve this problem. Is this a settings issue or could this be a graphics card issue? I'm working on an iMac 3.4 GHz Intel Core i7, 32GB memory with an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680MX 2048MB graphics card. I am completely lost so any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be a few different problems, we don't have enough info to properly help you, If you could post some screenshots and maybe upload the blend file so we can looks at it. Off the top of my head, 1. Make sure you're in the correct render engine (cycles/blender internal) 2. Was this anatomy model a blend file and obj or fbx? Not sure what you mean by composite node is connected correctly!? (That makes me think something is wrong there.) 3. Make sure graphics card has latest updates. 4. Material nodes may be wrong. 5. camera could be clipping 6. DOF could be on. 7. Lights not set to render

Comment: Check here, Possible Duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank