# Only the world color is being rendered

Tags: rendering, world

this is my first post. I'm fairly new to Blender (CG in general) and am having trouble rendering my scene because the only thing being rendered is the world color. I know there were a few other people on this site with this exact situation, but so far every object in my scene is render-activated in the Outliner, all the correct render layers are selected, I am rendering with CPU, and the camera Aperture is correctly set to zero, so I'm not sure what else to look at. It was working earlier today, so I guess I must've accidentally changed something?

Edit: My render slot isn't completely empty, only my world color (dark green) is being rendered.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/

Comment: Please read this link **carefully**: [Render result completely black](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank) where it reads: **Object or camera are in different render layer**. You have set the layers in a way that most of the scene is not included to be rendered. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSkdQ.png