# Nothing shows when rendering

Tags: rendering

As the tittle says, I've tried to render my model for quite a long time.
I read a post here but I couldn't solve anything, this is my current configuration for lamp/camera

I have already tried every solution in threads here, doesnt solve anything, I've actived nodes but still doesnt show up.

I dunno if it can be because the size of the camera and the lamp (The object is like 40cmx25cmx7,5cm and the lamp/camera is default size)

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I've tried by recommendation of another user to delete and add another camera, the problem still persists
[image]

[image]

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank/

Comment: Lamp and Layout.000 are restricted from rendering (see the Outliner in the top right box). Could it be the problem? This is one of the things explained in the links @DuarteFarrajotaRamos provided

Comment: No, the lamp and the "Layout.000" being restricted from rendering are not the problem, I already tested that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on Display Limits, and make sure that your object inside clipping zone:

[image]

All objects outside will not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your camera Focal Length to a number in the range 20mm — 105mm and see if that helps.

Focal length = 1m is a very exaggerated setting and you've probably set it by mistake

---

Edit:

also, your clipping Start and End settings are weird. Start must be smaller than End, and End should be much larger: try 1 meter!

---

To summarise: it looks like you have messed up with your camera settings. Creating a new camera and deleting the existing one should fix your problems.

Comment: No, doesnt work.

Comment: Please see the edit: does it work now?

Comment: No, sorry, I added a new camera, but only shows something when is right in the object (inside it) when I try to move it around doesnt show anything, or just a tiny part, but when I try to move the camera with ctr+alt+numpad0 I still cant see the object EDIT: Gonna edit the main post now with 2 new pictures

Comment: just try: blender allows to set "Start" bigger than "End". But yes result can be fun