# Blender only redering background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

If i change the background to transparent nothing renders, if i change it to white it renders a white screen etc. I made sure all my objects are turned on and have turned the mist setting off. I am not sure what to do. This is in cycles render also, i went through all the settings in the camera and made sure it was the same as the default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: if you have tried everything in those threads please post the blend https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/