# Rendering Animation Only showing world background?

Tags: rendering, objects, world

When I am in my file and choose to look at the work space in the render mode instead of object mode everything appears to look correct. The 2 planets and tie fighters I have moving are in place, lighting is hitting both objects and everything appears to work okay. However something is happening when I go to render my file, It appears that the world background I created, black with stars occasionally is the only thing that is appearing? Is it covering the cameras view? Are the other objects in the scene invisible? What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: Can you post screenshots or include Render Layer information? I'd like to see it happening; I think it's something elementary but difficult to nail down with only text. Did you tinker with Cycles display/render settings to make things 'invisible' to the camera?