# No render at all on iMac

Tags: rendering, osx

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere but I can't find much. When I try to render even the default startup cube, all I get is a blank screen with a few orange crosses in the middle. After some searching, I've found that my Mac's NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M does not support CUDA, which is why when I click on CUDA in Blender user preferences, I'm told 'No compatible GPUs found'. Trouble is, I get this with OpenCL as well. Does this mean that I just can't render anything in Blender? Even when I'm on None, which I assume means it's using my Mac's CPU, I get nothing. Am I missing something? Thanks.
[image: What I get when I click Render]

Comment: This question is asked quite often. you can use the [search] box at the top to find similar questions. Please read through the following links that list some of the many causes for blank rendering: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank

Comment: Go to the top menu (File, edit, view, RENDER) On RENDER menu select Open GL RENDER image. If you DON´T render what you see on your viewport then there´s nothing else to do but to go back to Blender 2.62 or change computer's graphic card to CUDA support (GTX 770i or above). (even so it´s risky). Play for sure, go for a Titan X card. Happy Blendering.