# 3d viewport rendering black

Tags: rendering

Hello im another newbie here.

So ive been looking around for a solution to this but i can't realy find any.
I can render my image but i can't use the rendered option in 3D Viewport it just turns the scene completely black, can sombody help my solve this? sorry if this is a stupid question.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up/67491

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question gets asked quite often. Please use the search box at the top. Also read carefully through the many causes of blank rendering listed here: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490) and here: [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632). If none of those work for you then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to add more information, and add images that illustrate how you set up your project and settings.