# My render is complete gray or transparent

Tags: rendering

My render view is completely gray and I don't know why.

[image: Gray Render View]
<sup>*Gray render view.*</sup>

[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87wS0.png)
[Render Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwB4h.jpg)
[Outliner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jH5m.jpg)
[Camera Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqdnG.jpg)

Comment: Don't know how to post here properly sorry please I need help

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: This question gets asked quite often. Please use the search box at the top. Also look through the many causes of blank rendering here: [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490) and here: [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632)

Answer (score 0):

First: Select the object you want to appear on the render. Check the eye icon is active. Check the camera icon is active.
Second: With the object selected, press "." on the numpad. This will focus on the selectd object. Now, press CTRL+ALT+"0" (zero on the numpad). This will make your current view your CAMERA view. This is ASSUMING you have a camera on scene. If not, create one, and go to step 1 again.
Finally, when you see your viewport and camera; on the outliner select your camera and go to CLIPPING. Set END to : 10 km. This should allow you to extensively look deep into your scene.
Finally if all of the above fails: Go to object properties (the cube icon on the properties region area) and scroll down to CYCLE settings: Make sure CAMERA is CHECKED for ray visibility:
[image]

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller