# Nothing showing up in rendered view (2.79)

Tags: rendering

To preface, I'm fairly new to Blender. 
I normally work in 2.8, but my current project requires me to work in 2.79.

That being said, I'm having an issue with the rendered view in Cycles. Earlier in my project, I was able to switch in & out of rendered to view my models. I'm not sure what I messed up, but now nothing is showing up when I enter rendered view. In material view, everything is visible and I can see my models just fine. But when I switch into rendered view, everything disappears including the grid.

Does anyone know how to fix this? 
[image: Photo attached for reference]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank)

Comment: @Sazerac I believe the issue is that the render is paused, which is not addressed in that question.

Answer (score 1):

You have inadvertently 'paused' the render:

[image: screenshot of 3D view toolbar pause button]

Click the button in the *3D View* header toolbar again to un-pause.