# Blender Does not Render Image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, image

My image is not rendering in cycles render. I can see everything in the rendered viewport but when i do a final render i only see a Black and grey checkered screen. After a while blender will crash.

I have tried to uncheck sequencer and render but same thing happens. All the objects are not hidden and fully seen. I have tried both using f12 and the render image button in the menu to render the image.

Would appreciate if someone can help me out its been a pain trying to figure out the issues ty :)

[image]

Comment: With no information on your scene is hard to help you, nobody can guess your scene and settings. Please **read carefully** through the answers on these pages: [Possible causes for blank output on rendering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632) and [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490). Try the proposed solutions. If you still can't solve your problem, then use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question to add relevant info.

Comment: try rendering other things and see if the same thing happens.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a few View Layers you should properly manage it render settings.

Please share some screenshot with us!

Comment: please use comments to request information, not the answers section.

Comment: ok, but I posted the guess that most likely.. 

if there'll be a screenshot I can edit the answer, right?

Comment: You can always use the edit link under your question to add detail. We love detailed answers and anything that might help other users.