# Why Is My Transparency Shader Not Working

Tags: modeling

I just installed the Released Candidate version of Blender and noticed that a couple of things are missing. Im using CYCLES as render engine.

First, I can no longer make the TRANSPARENCY SHADER to work properly. My goal is to KEYFRAME the FAC so that I can make the object disappear at a certain point. (Please see video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAEdu0Qeuts&feature=youtu.be) But as you can see, when Played around with the values of the FAC, it will create this weird shapes and not fully disappear.

Thanks

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Your second point has been asked before and already has an answer, so this might get closed as duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141144/where-are-the-outliner-toggles-in-2-8/141145#141145

Comment: Maybe try to increase the Transparency value in the Render panel > Light Paths? For your second question, you'll find all these option if you click on the key icon on the top right of the Outliner panel you show

Comment: @moonboots i tried setting it to 20 but nothing happened :)

Comment: I think you are only changing the material transparency for the heat spreader but not for all of the other objects. To me it seems that the heat spreader is disappearing fine, but not the other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened but I was able to solve it.

1. I went to edit mode and found a weird formation on the faces that didn't disappeared.
2. I deleted those faces and recreated a new FACE.
3. Everything worked after that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that everything works normally, but you have a second material on those faces that doesn't turn transparent (and those faces just happen to form the observed weird shapes due to your mesh).

So to solve this you can either make all faces have the same material or have a transparency node and keyframes for each of those materials.

(If this answer does not work for you, please provide a .blend since other problems might show the same symptoms)

Happy Blending! :)

Comment: I did a thorough inspection and for some reason, a section at the top FACES of the IHS was not affected by the  TRANSPARENT SHADER. 

I deleted them, and then created a new face from the same object and it work. That's the part I don't understand. Could be a bug?

Now it's working perfectly fine!!!

Thanks