# Problem with eevee rendering

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm not sure why it is ok in the viewer but it is like photo 2 after eevee rendering . Please advice. Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess that's some kind of overlapping geometry. Make sure there is no other geometry enabled for *rendering*. Go to the outliner and disable the object for rendering by clicking on the camera icon, if enabled still: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlDmf.png

Comment: Its work .Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the outliner toggles in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141144/where-are-the-outliner-toggles-in-2-8)

Comment: @brockmann Don't really see how this question is similar to the question you linked. Seems like this is [Duplicate answer vs duplicate question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question)

Comment: Ahh, ok - wasn't aware of this post. Do you find a better one? @RayMairlot

Comment: yea , thank you for your solution

Comment: @brockmann You should add this to the answer section so it can be accepted.