# Blender 2.8 does not render view port image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

At the end ~26:00 of this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUoE-1vYXPI

the selected view port is rendered. In my case, however, the render result differs from the view port:

[image]

Why isn't blender rendering the current selection instead of stuff from another layer? How can I render 
only what's in the view port?

Comment: Hello :). Objects need to be manually disabled from render. You can use the outliner toggles for that. It's the *camera* icon. https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/141144/