# Why does the render look different from the viewport?

Tags: rendering

In my rendered image, there are weird circular patterns on the surface and part of the brick wall that I use as a backround is cut off,while it is portrayed correctly in my viewport.

[image]
[image: **enter image description here**]

I also struggled with the fact that scaling didn't change in the viewport properly (for example with the frosting of my donut) until I pressed "I" > "LocRotScale". Maybe the fact that transformation doesn't happen on its own has something to do with it? Do I maybe have a setting turned on that doesn't let the objects in my scene transform properly? I added a link with my blender file, in case you wanna see for yourself.

[image]

Comment: There is a garbage collection called "Archives", disable it and hopefully it will render fine. Textures are missing so I can not verify to 100%. Also up your samples to 700+

Comment: this fixed the problem, thank you so much!! I'm curious though, since the objects in the archive were not marked as visible (meaning I pressed on the eye buttons next to them) but the archives box was checked. What is the difference and why does it interfere with the render, even when the objects themselves are not being rendered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the outliner toggles in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141144/where-are-the-outliner-toggles-in-2-8)