# Blender Object Visibility Controls at version 2.80+

Tags: interface

At Blender versions prior to 2.80, it was simple to toggle and keyframe the visibility - either in the viewport or the render by manipulating the buttons in the Outliner.

[image: visibility control buttons]

Those buttons aren't present in Blender 2.80 - how do I control the visibility as before?

Comment: It’s certainly similar, @Gorgious, but I think it’s coming from a different angle in that this is a change to the interface rather than loading files from an earlier version.

Comment: You are right. This one is a duplicate though : https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/141144/86891

Comment: It is - well found!

Comment: It took me several minutes to find it :) but I was sure I saw this question asked and answered several times before but couldn't figure the keywords (damn stackexchange search !!)

Comment: Yeah - it’s something I’ve wondered for a while and only today happened across the ‘fix’ and so created the Q with and A to share the knowledge. Good that it’s already been answered - that had passed me by!! It’s a bit confusing losing those icons IMO. Seems a big loss for very little saved screen space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The visibility options are still available in the Overview window and operate as before, but are hidden by default. They can be re-enabled via the 'Filter' drop-down which provides various toggle buttons for the various additional controls :

[image: object visibility controls]