# Character animation visible in viewport but not in render

Tags: rendering, animation, octane-render-engine

I've downloaded a animated character from mixamo but when I render the final animation he's locked.

I've baked all the actions, make visible during render, but the character is stuck only during render. The strange thing is that in my viewport I can see the animation. I'm using octane for blender.

[image: outline]

Comment: How does your outliner look like? Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141144/where-are-the-outliner-toggles-in-2-8

Comment: Did you render as an animation?

Comment: @brockmann i've updated my question with outline image

Comment: @Relevred yes, i've tried also to save it with a sequence of png but nothing changed

Comment: Make sure *1 image* is rendering properly in the first place. If that's rendering fine using cycles, might be an issue with octane.

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is, provide your blend file using blend-exchange.com

Comment: @brockmann when i render, all the other animated things move... i think it's a problem with the character animation.. i've tried also an other character with different animation but the same thing happen

Comment: @Relevred i'm providing blend file

Comment: sorry, the blend file is too big, any solutions?

Comment: Try google drive

Comment: ok, done... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X9k29cvKSzqvgDJV_V8_WxbMOasLyMy5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to change Octane  server setting (in the Render Props tab)
Render all meshes as reshapable
[image]