# Cycles Final Render is Black in Blender 2.91.0

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I need some help with one of my Blender projects. I was making this simple interior design render with the help of fspy. I made some simple objects and some materials. I didn't check before if I can render an image as a preview. I only relied on the rendered view while making the scene.

If I were to hit F12 and render an image, it just renders pitch black. I tried many ways to fix this by researching other forums and questions but, none of them worked. One weird thing I found is when I render and allow it to denoise, I can see a faint light from where the window is supposed to be.

I appreciate any help to fix this.

I uploaded the .blend file to my google drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12-bBib8uqL1by7ngnXT_2xxHRJFMgC4L/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello :). Your Window and Door Boolean objects aren't disabled in render. They block any light coming into the room. That's why it's black.

Comment: Related: [Where are the outliner toggles in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/141144/78972)

Comment: @JachymMichal thank you very much! I was trying to fix this problem for an embarrassing amount of time.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project :)