# Mysterious Green Thing Appearing only when rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm not sure why this is happening but when I try to render my animation, a green thing pops up in the render. The object is not there when looking at the animation in the viewport but appears when I try to render. Depending on what the starting frame is (the entire scene is 400 frames long), the object appears in different locations. Below is what appears when I try to export.

[image: This is a screenshot mid-render. The green thing behind the cupcake shouldn't be there.]

I render in cycles and I've tried rendering both with CPU and GPU, different frame sizes, differing light bouncing amounts. Even different computers. Nothing I do seems to work.

Also I should note that the issue started suddenly, as I would export the scene before with no problem but when I changed the world color, that's when the thing started popping up.

Comment: Is it possible you have an object turned off from view in the viewport but still enabled for rendering?  You have to explicitly turn off things you don't want rendered even if they are not shown in your viewport.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the outliner toggles in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141144/where-are-the-outliner-toggles-in-2-8)

Comment: The object could be hidden in the viewport. By going to your collection view (typically in the top right) it doesnt look like there are many objects there so you could look through your collection to see what objects have an eye with a cross through it (this means they arent visible in the viewport however they can still show up in the render)