# Parts of Rig only showing up in Render, and not viewport?

Tags: mesh, armature

[image: Current blender view and render]

Why are only some parts of the Rig showing up in the viewport?

Answer (score 1):

Open the *Filter* menu in the outliner, there enable the [*Disabled in Viewport* toggle ("monitor icon")](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/141145/107598). Now you have these monitor icons in the outliner on the right side, between the "eye icon" (hide in viewport) and the "camera icon" (disable in render).

Click the "monitor icon" in the outliner for the greyed-out entries and they will be back.

Comment: I really appreciate it thank you very much!