# Instance to Collection, Unhiding Objects

Tags: instances

So I'm trying to mirror Collections, and the easiest and fastest way I found is just to make an Instance of that collection and -1 the scale. It works fine the only problem is that the objects inside the collection that are hidden in the instance they appear unhidden. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes it looks like hidding an object in the collection in viewport won't hide the same object in the instance. That said if you hide it for render it won't be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the global visibility (monitor icon) instead of the eye icon to hide objects in instanced collections. Or go to Object properties > Visibility > Uncheck "Show in ... Viewports"

[image]

If you don't see the Monitor icon in the outliner, please refer to : [Where are the outliner toggles in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141144/where-are-the-outliner-toggles-in-2-8)