# Refresh object mode from edit mode

Tags: rigging, edit-mode, pose-mode, object-mode

How I can solve this problem?

The mesh looks fine in *Edit Mode* and when the rig is in *Rest Position*:
[image: Edit Mode]

But when the rig is in *Pose Position* the right hand has bad deformation even if the model is still in rest position and all transformations are cleared. The left hand is fine.
[image: Object Mode]

---

@ TheLabCat, I struggle to understand your explanation, although it is clear, because I am not familiar with the menus due to my lack of knowledge of the software.

**Blend file**: [Upload Rig](https://mega.nz/file/k19lFCiD#5CAsqDPFb5cTUv1PCLRo2U9C0xOMlJXGzNEf5cpCRC8)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please describe in detail what the issue is, supported by [accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Reset the armature's pose.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not ask us to simply figure out what the problem is based on a couple of screenshots. Add text details to avoid confusion. Thankfully, the problem you are trying to point out seems pretty clear to me at the moment: When in object mode, the wrist is deformed improperly. The base mesh is not damaged, as shown in edit mode.

It looks like you’ve got some sort of deform modifier set up, probably an armature modifier, and when you are in edit mode, the effects of this modifier are hidden. You don’t need to refresh anything, you just need to figure out why the [armature] deform isn’t working the way you want it to.

I suspect that the wrist bone is detached from the lower arm bone and has been moved, or the weights are not set up properly and an entirely different bone is deforming the wrist.

To diagnose this, you can (with the armature selected and active) go into the Properties editor -> Armature tab -> View panel, and check “In Front” to show the armature through the mesh. If the wrist bones look fine, something else is deforming the wrist when it shouldn’t, and that means your weights aren’t set up properly. Search on YouTube or this Stack Exchange for explanations of what vertex weights are, and how to configure them properly with armatures.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem** is the wrong bone roll of the right forearm bone. Your modded game model is controlled by two armatures:

- the first one named "*Rig*" has only deformation bones that deform the mesh "*Female Body*". It's used by the game and has tiny bones which are all weird aligned (game-optimized?). Such a rig is not comfortable to use for animation. That's the reason for the second rig.
- the second rig "*control_rig*" is as the name suggests a control rig. It has all these nice control bones with custom shapes and supports inverse kinematics (IK). The changes of this rig are propagated to the *Rig* by *Copy Transforms* bone constraints on the deformation bones.

This means that if you move a control bone of the *control_rig*, the corresponding deformation bone in the *Rig* armature copies the transformation to itself, and the mesh is deformed accordingly.

It's necessary that the control bone and the corresponding deformation bone are at the same spot and have the same bone roll values to make the copy transformation mechanism work properly.

The deform bone "*b__R_Hand__*" causes the bad deformation on the hand but it's controlled and moved by its parent "*b__R_Forearm__*". And this bone copies its transformation from the control bone "*R_Forearm*". The *Copy Transforms* bone constraint reveals this relationship between the deform bone and the control bone:

[image: copy transforms]

**How to fix it**

A lot of the objects in the blend file are hidden for the viewport or disabled for selection. You need to [activate the restriction toggles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/141144/107598) in the outliner first.

1. now make the *Rig* selectable ("arrow" icon) and active in the viewport ("monitor" icon) and select it.
2. both armatures *Rig* and *control_rig* are now in *Pose* mode for some reason. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to *Edit* mode (*Rig* selected -> *Edit*)
3. hide *control_rig* in the outline ("eye" icon) so you can see the tiny deform bones better
4. look for the bone named "*b__R_Forearm__*" of *Rig*. It's at the elbow right at the same position as the elbow bone (and the hidden control bone). Click 2x if necessary to select the correct one.
5. open the side panel (<kbd>N</kbd>), look for the bone roll (-137°), and enter the correct bone roll: `-132.99d`. This is the bone roll of the corresponding control bone "*R_Forearm*" in *control_rig*.

[image: fix it]

That's it. Here's the result:

[image: result]